# How to connect from user location to destination?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, google-maps

I want to `draw` a line from `current` user `location` to `destination` using `google` map

I have this `hardcoded` value, how to make it `dynamic`.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m28!1m12!1m3!1d62184.85911505553!2d77.54398420640405!3d13.064056093502584!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m13!3e6!4m5!1s0x3bae229f7a8debe1%3A0x4d80f1d259c7e7ac!2sVidyaranyapura%2C+Bengaluru%2C+Karnataka!3m2!1d13.0857908!2d77.55609799999999!4m5!1s0x3bae1782c59f1f99%3A0x536d89574c4f1216!2sNagavara%2C+Bengaluru%2C+Karnataka!3m2!1d13.0422567!2d77.6135523!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1486457746829" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**my question:** my destination will be fixed like `var dest = "yelhanka";` i want to draw `line from` `current user location` to my `destination` `dynamically`(i,e yelhanka)

Comment: First of, I removed your API key from your post, you should never post that. To actually answer your question, you should look into the [directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints) they have

Comment: @George, actually i was not aware of this `directions API` thanks alot

Comment: @George, could you please guide me to change my `api key` please, as i'm not able to change it